# "WebExtension::executeScript: content script injected VM149:1" in Chrome loading React app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

Haven't come across this message in all our testing and not sure if it is related to the actual issue.

Basically, have a user agreement text box that the user has to "read" (scroll to the bottom of) before they can click the box that they agree to it. Pretty standard stuff. We launched the web app Sunday and of about 100 users, two have stated that even though they scrolled to the bottom of the text box, the box did not become clickable.

The first one never got back to me, but the second user did and sent me a screenshot of the console:

> WebExtension::executeScript: content script injected VM149:1

They are indeed scrolling to the bottom of the box. Initially, we just thought they were scrolling to the bottom of the page and they thought that is what they needed to do. But we were wrong.

I can't find much on it. Not even sure if it is related to the issue since it wasn't labeled as an error.

Both users are using Chrome latest version on Windows. We have them try Edge or Firefox and it works fine. Seems to be isolated to Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely to be the [Okta](https://okta.com) browser plugin.  I have it installed and it produces this same error.  The source of the plugin script is:

```
(function(code) {
    if (eval("typeof Okta === 'undefined'")) {
        eval("window.Okta = {};");
        eval(code);
        console.log("WebExtension::executeScript: content script injected")
    } else {
        console.log("WebExtension::executeScript: skipping eval script")
    }
}
)(" /* A LOT OF MINIFIED CODE HERE */ ");
```